# jQuery ui autocomplete IE 11 issue

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

When I return a large result set in my autocomplete source function, the results do not appear in IE. With chrome and Firefox everything works fine.

The IE Console doesn't show any errors or warnings and when I debug my code, the result variable has all values.

I tried to slice the result set and set a timeout value, but no luck.

This is my autocomplete function:

```
 $( "#" + autoCompleteEle ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    autoFocus: true,
    delay: 1000,
    maxResults: 100,
    timeout: 60000,
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var res = [];
        var resStr  = "";
        var cn = "";
        var owner = "";
        var nrfLocalizedDescrs = "";
        var noResultsLabel = "No Results";

        var roleObj = {};
        var term = request.term.toLowerCase();
        if(term.substr(0,1).indexOf("*") == -1){
            var spinnElement = $("#" + autoCompleteEle ).parent();
            //spinnElement.wrap("<div id='spinnWrappper'></div>");
            initSpinner( spinnElement, "20%", "35%" );

            setTimeout(function () {
                var queryRes = null;
                queryRes = queryRoles(term, clientValue);
                var selRowId = $("#roleGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
                var system = $("#" + selRowId + "_system").val();
                var roleGrid = $("#roleGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
                var roleDnArray = $.map(roleGrid, function (item) { 
                    if( (typeof(item.roleDn) != "undefined") && (typeof(item.system) != "undefined") && item.system.toLowerCase() == system.toLowerCase() ){
                        return item.roleDn.toLowerCase();
                    }   
                });

                for(key in queryRes){
                    if( roleDnArray.indexOf(key.toLowerCase() ) == -1){
                        if (queryRes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            roleObj = queryRes[key];
                            if(typeof(roleObj.map.attr.map.CN) != "undefined"){
                                cn = roleObj.map.attr.map.CN.list[0];
                            }
                            if(typeof(roleObj.map.attr.map.Owner) != "undefined"){
                                owner = roleObj.map.attr.map.Owner.list[0];
                            }
                            if(typeof(roleObj.map.attr.map.nrfLocalizedDescrs) != "undefined"){
                                var roleDescStr = roleObj.map.attr.map.nrfLocalizedDescrs.list[0];
                                if(roleDescStr.indexOf("|") > -1){
                                    var descPattern1 = roleDescStr.indexOf("~") + 1;
                                    var descPattern2 = roleDescStr.indexOf("|");
                                    nrfLocalizedDescrs = roleDescStr.substring(descPattern1, descPattern2);

                                }else{
                                    var descPattern1 = roleDescStr.indexOf("~") + 1;
                                    var descPattern2 = roleDescStr.length -1;
                                    nrfLocalizedDescrs = roleDescStr.substr(descPattern1, descPattern2);
                                }
                            }

                            var labelStr = cn;
                            var nameStr = key;
                            res.push({label: labelStr, name: nameStr, description: nrfLocalizedDescrs, owner: owner });
                            //cache.push(userObj);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!res.length) {
                    res = [noResultsLabel];
                }   
                res = sortByKey(res, 'label');
                $(".spinner").remove();
                response(res.slice(0, 100));
             }, 0); 
        }else{

        }
    },
    select: function(e, ui) {
        if (ui.item.label === "No Results") {
            event.preventDefault();
        }else{
            var rowId;
            $(this).prop('title', ui.item.name);
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            //set roleDn and description
            rowId = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').prop('id');
            if( ui.item.description != "" &&  ui.item.description != null){
                $('#roleGrid').jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'roleDescription', ui.item.description);
            }
            $('#roleGrid').jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'roleDn', ui.item.name);
            $('#roleGrid').jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'roleStatus', 'new');
            if(ui.item.owner != "" && ui.item.owner != null){
                $('#roleGrid').jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'ownerDn', ui.item.owner);
                setRoleOwnerTooltip( rowId, ui.item.owner, false );
            }
        }
    },
    search: function(event, ui) { 
        //$('.spinner').show();
    },
    response: function(event, ui) {
       //$('.spinner').hide();
    },
    create: function () {
            $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $('<li data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body">')
                    .append('<a>' + '<i class="fa fa-list-alt autocompleteItem"></i>' + item.label +'</a>')
                    .appendTo(ul)
                    .tooltip({title: item.description,  placement : 'right'});
            };
    },
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item.label === "No Results") {
            event.preventDefault();
        }else{

        }
    }
});
```

css:

```
    .ui-autocomplete {
       position: absolute;
       top: 100%;
       left: 0;
       z-index: 1000;
       float: left;
       display: none;
       min-width: 200px;
       max-width: 900px;
       max-height: 500px;
       overflow-y: auto;
       overflow-x: hidden;
      _width: 500px;
       padding: 4px 0;
       list-style: none;
       background-color: #ffffff;
       border-color: #999999;
       border-style: solid;
       border-width: 1px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
     -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
      border-top-right-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
       border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
     -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 5px 10px;
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 5px 10px;
  }
```

Versions:

- IE11
- jQuery 1.10.2
- jQuery-ui 1.10.4

Comment: In IE debugger  DOM viewer see if the autocomplete element is available in DOM.

Comment: yes, the input element exists and has the class ui-autocomplete-input. the problem appears only with very large result sets.